# Fetching, Rendering and Positioning images in a PDF file using Pyhon

Tags: python, opencv, img2pdf

I have a folder where i have stored multiple .bmp images, which I want to place in a .pdf file in a structured manner. Can anyone assist.

Say I have 100 .bmp images in a folder named as image1, image2....image100.

I want to display these images in the PDF file as mentioned below, say 5 lines per PDF page.

-image1 and image2 placed side by side in line 1

-image3 and image4 placed side by side in line 2

-image5 and image6 placed side by side in line 3

...

...

-image99 and image100 placed side by side in line 50

the code should,

1. Fetch the images from the foleder
2. Render the size and resolution of these images as per requirement
3. Position the images in specific location in the PDF

Answer (score 3):

I looked around for the solution and found the answer in FPDF library.
I am sharing the very rough solution i cobbled up.

```
##install the FPDF liabrary using pip install fpfd

from fpdf import FPDF

def createPDF():
    fpdf=FPDF()

##To open a new PDF document
    fpdf.add_page()

##set for for the text to be added
    fpdf.set_font("Arial", size=10)

##adding text to the pdf document
    fpdf.text(22, 10, txt="MASTER")
    fpdf.text(57, 10, txt="SAMPLE")

    
##adding images to the pdf document

fpdf.image("CMYK-M.jpg", 15, 15, w=50)


fpdf.image("CMYK-S.jpg", 50, 15, w=50)

##To save the PDF document
fpdf.output("REPORT001.pdf")
```